# How to deploy a sample Mule project on PCF?

Tags: mule, cloud, mule-studio, cloud-foundry

I want to deploy my mule project to PCF . [I referred to Mulesoft Documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/deploying-to-pcf). But it fails to provide me a clear understanding. I don't want to use Anypoint Platform but deploy directly to the PCF web services using cloud foundry.

And is there any specific Mule Buildpack?(like java,go etc.)

Thanks for the help, In advance

Answer (score 0):

There are community buildpacks for AnyPoint applications with the Mule runtime, e.g. https://github.com/jdeoliveira/mule-cf-java-buildpack

---

In broad terms, you open a command line and navigate to your build artefact folder. From there you run `cf push` and specify the location of the buildpack.

e.g

```
# cf login with your credentials

cf push mymuleapp -b https://github.com/jdeoliveira/mule-cf-java-buildpack.git
```

This will create a droplet with your application and the Mule buildpack.

Comment: Yes. it is but how do I use it? can you give me a example. I tried to but i could not, Its not understood by me. Looks like it is some java package. What do I have to do deploy the buildpack first. I am new to this. Help